# Pass Javascript variable to Rails path

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to pass a Javascript variable to a Rails path?

For example, I have in my html.erb file:

```
<script>
for (i=1, i< numSteps, i++){
   var step = i
   td.innerHTML = <%= project_step_path(@project, step) %>
}
</script>
```

But this doesn't work since step is a Javascript variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- JavaScript runs on the browser
- Rails runs on the server.

They can not run together.

Comment: thanks for your response!  do you have any suggestions for how I might accomplish what I want to do instead?

Comment: Just do the loop on the server side? Unless it was just an example and you're trying to do something different..

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the Ruby will run on the server. It will generate some text. That text is sent to the browser. The browser will parse it as HTML and JS.

You can't do bi-directional synchronous communication in a single HTTP request/response.

So no.

Each time you want to send data from client side JavaScript to server side Ruby you need to issue a new HTTP request.

Issuing such a request can be done by:

- setting `location`
- submitting a form
- using the XMLHttpRequest object
- generating an element (such as a script or an image) that can have an external `src`
- and a host of other methods.